# Ubuntu 18.04 certificate validation failure

Tags: 18.04, certificates

On a (relatively) fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04, I'm experiencing failures related to certificate validation. First the Dropbox installer could not download the binary client. I also notice that `wget` is unable to valdiate certificates with domains such as `dropbox.com` and `github.com` which are surely configured correctly. I'm also unable to install any Ruby gems. Any suggestions on fixing would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the solution was to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates`. Not sure why this was needed, but fixed things for me.

**EDIT**

Since it's somewhat related, there was another fix necessary for Java [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50103533/123695).

Comment: I don't know what changed on my 18.04 setup to need to do this, but something did, and this fixed it. So, thanks!

Comment: it worked like charm. Thanks a lot.